# error in MemoryImage not defined in package pdf/widgets.dart

Tags: flutter, pdf-generation, flutter-image

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as material ;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;


class PdfParagraphApi {
  
  static Future<void> generate(key) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();
    final img = pw.MemoryImage(await rootBundle.load('assets/img.png')).buffer.asUint8List();
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.MultiPage(
        build: (context) => <pw.Widget>[
          pw.Image(img),
       ]),
    );
  }
}
```

i'm trying to create a pdf with an image inside it and i'm using the library pdf/widgets.dart to create the image as i found in flutters documentation but i'm facing a problem.
the error message is the following :
The function 'MemoryImage' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'MemoryImage', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'MemoryImage'.dartundefined_function

```
insert image into pdf not working
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `pw.MemoryImage` with `material.MemoryImage`, because MemoryImage comes from the painting library, which is included inside the material library.

Comment: i already tried so but i get another error saying that The argument type 'MemoryImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PdfImage*'

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the below import:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as material ;
```

with this `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

Comment: i already tried so but i get another error saying that The argument type 'MemoryImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PdfImage*'

Answer (score 0):

Try this below way:

### Imports you need

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'dart:typed_data';
    import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
    import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart ' as pw;
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

and in the top you need to define the image you want to print `_imageFile = someImage`:

```
  Uint8List? _imageFile ;
```

Then this is the function to make an image to pdf and save it in the Downloads Folder

```
    Future getPdf() async {
  var random = Random();
  var uniqueNum = random.nextInt(99999);
  //get storage permission
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> storagePermission = await [
    Permission.storage,
  ].request();
  pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();
  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (context) {
        return pw.Expanded(
          child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(_imageFile), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
  String path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      ExternalPath.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

  String mainPath = "$path/Report$uniqueNum.pdf";

  File pdfFile = File(mainPath);
  pdfFile.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
}
```